# "Respected" vs. "Respectable"

Tags: adjectives

I want to know the difference between *respected* and *respectable*. In which circumstances, can I conclude that a certain person/peaple/object is respected or respectable?

For example, what's the correct choice in these sentences:

> 1) All my friends come from very <sub>........................</sub> families.
>   **a. respected**             **b. respectable**
>
> 2) She tried to make her husband look a bit more <sub>.......................</sub> before going out.
>   **a. respected**             **b. respectable**

Comment: Respected - for those already admired/respected. Respectable - for those who deserve respect.

Comment: There comes a question then! What's 'respectful'?

Comment: These examples are well chosen.  Either word works for 1, but only *respectable* works for 2.